# java.lang.ClassCastException while fetching data from hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to print details of fetched data using `HQL` query as follow

```
List list = sess.createQuery("from PostMessages as pm "
                    + " left join pm.postImageses as pi "
                    + " left join pm.videosDescriptions as vd "
                    + "where pm.messageid=:msgId")
                       .setParameter("msgId", msgId).list();

            List<PostMessages> result = (List<PostMessages>) list;
            Iterator itr = result.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                PostMessages pm = (PostMessages) itr.next();
                System.out.print("msg: " + pm.getMessage());
                System.out.print(" type: " + pm.getMessageType());
                Set images = pm.getPostImageses();
                Iterator itr1 = images.iterator();
                while (itr1.hasNext()) {
                    PostImages pi = (PostImages) itr1.next();
                    System.out.print("id: " + pi.getImageId());
                    System.out.print("desc: " + pi.getImgDesc());
                }
                Set videos = pm.getVideosDescriptions();
                Iterator itr2 = videos.iterator();
                while (itr2.hasNext()) {
                    VideosDescription vd = (VideosDescription) itr1.next();
                    System.out.print("id: " + vd.getVideoId());
                    System.out.print("desc: " + vd.getDescription());
                }
            }
```

But this is showing following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to 
hibernetMappings.PostMessages
    at hibernetMappings.TestPost.main(TestPost.java:40)
```

How to resolve this exception.

Comment: Is this line 40 > PostMessages pm = (PostMessages) itr.next(); ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to do this.

```
  Iterator itr = result.iterator();
```

to

```
  Iterator<PostMessages> itr = result.iterator();
```

Also change

```
List<PostMessages> list = sess.createQuery("from PostMessages as pm "
                    + " left join fetch pm.postImageses as pi "
                    + " left join fetch pm.videosDescriptions as vd "
                    + "where pm.messageid=:msgId")
                       .setParameter("msgId", msgId).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a select clause to your query:

```
select distinct pm from PostMessages as pm ...
```

Note that the left joins are useless. If the goal is to retrieve the post messages with their images and video descriptions in a single query, you should use `left join fetch`.

You should also use an `Iterator<PostMessages>`, instead of a raw Iterator. And the entity should be named `PostMessage`, and not `PostMessages`: each instance is one message, not several. `getImageses()` should be `getImages()`.

Comment: Nizat I have one doubt. Insted of writing above query if I only write `from PostMessages` will it also load its all mapping data

Comment: Turn SQL logging on, ans see what Hibernate generates. SQL logging should be on during development.